# jQuery/Javascript Charting library

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there any charting library which provides an `odometer` like in this [image](http://static4.depositphotos.com/1024437/363/v/950/depositphotos_3631665-Black-and-Red-Odometer.jpg)?

[image]

I've gone through Highcharts but there sint like this. Where can I find an odometer like provided which shows digit values only, not a gauge or something.

I want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jDkzg/). Since this is hardcoded, I want a library which will do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an SVG library before named RaphaelJS to generate cool charts.

Comment: Anything else other than this? This seems to be complex. :)

Comment: How about http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/ ? Have you seen that already?

Comment: Bingo. Thats what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- You may want to look and adapt the Google [Chart's Gauge](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge.html).
- [RGraph](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/rgraph/RGraph_20091010/) has an [odometer](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/rgraph/RGraph_20091010/examples/odo.html) plot

As for charting libraries and their general features see this [Comparison of JavaScript charting frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks)

Comment: As I've already stated that I dont want a Gauge Instead, I want a digital meter something like the image provided.